# Link threads in PDF is not in correct position wherever citations breaks over two lines

Tags: hyperref

I'm using the below coding in a Tex file, and getting links for citations. Please see the below coding.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hypernat}
\usepackage[dvips,breaklinks,bookmarks=false,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=blue,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue,
}%

\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Calibration of the model}\label{SS:calibration}

The software package \citep{SVM08} was used to obtain the
$\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\mu$ that best fit dataset 6 given
in Table~\ref{tab1}.  Here, $V_{0}$ was taken to be the
volume at $t = 0$, i.e. $V_{0} = 0.34\,{\rm cm}^{3}$ and
only the first four data points from dataset~6 were used
for calibration.  A routine was written in \citet{SVM08}
that includes the optimization tool, \textit{lsqcurvefit},
a \citet{SVM08} built-in function. This function solves the
following optimization problem using least squares dummy text \citep{Matlab77}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[MATLAB 7.7(R2008b)]{SVM08}
{\bibname Matlab 7.7} (R2008b) \textit{Copyright 1984--2008}, Natick, Massachusetts, USA: The MathWorks, Inc.

\bibitem[MATLAB 7.7 and Optimization Toolbox 4.1(R2008b)]{Matlab77}
{\bibname Matlab 7.7 and Optimization Toolbox 4.1} (R2008b) \textit{Copyright 1984--2008}, Natick, Massachusetts, USA: The MathWorks, Inc.

\end{thebibliography}
```

After generating the PDF, the links which are breaking over 2 lines are not showing in correct position, please look into the screenshot.[image]

Could anyone help me on solving this issue?

Regards

S. Vinayagamurthy

---

I'm using the below coding in a Tex file, and getting links for citations. Please see the below coding.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hypernat}
\usepackage[dvips,breaklinks,bookmarks=false,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=blue,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue,
}%

\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Calibration of the model}\label{SS:calibration}

The software package \citep{SVM08} was used to obtain the
$\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\mu$ that best fit dataset 6 given
in Table~\ref{tab1}.  Here, $V_{0}$ was taken to be the
volume at $t = 0$, i.e. $V_{0} = 0.34\,{\rm cm}^{3}$ and
only the first four data points from dataset~6 were used
for calibration.  A routine was written in \citet{SVM08}
that includes the optimization tool, \textit{lsqcurvefit},
a \citet{SVM08} built-in function. This function solves the
following optimization problem using least squares dummy text \citep{Matlab77}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[MATLAB 7.7(R2008b)]{SVM08}
{\bibname Matlab 7.7} (R2008b) \textit{Copyright 1984--2008}, Natick, Massachusetts, USA: The MathWorks, Inc.

\bibitem[MATLAB 7.7 and Optimization Toolbox 4.1(R2008b)]{Matlab77}
{\bibname Matlab 7.7 and Optimization Toolbox 4.1} (R2008b) \textit{Copyright 1984--2008}, Natick, Massachusetts, USA: The MathWorks, Inc.

\end{thebibliography}
```

After generating the PDF, the links which are breaking over 2 lines are not showing in correct position, please look into the screenshot.

[image]

Could anyone help me on solving this issue?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The driver for `dvips` does *not* support broken links across lines, see section "Wrapped/broken link support" of `hyperref`'s [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf). It also says about option `breaklinks`:

> The option `breaklinks` is intended for internal use. But it can be
>   used to force link wrapping, e.g. when printing a  document. However,
>   when such a document is converted to PDF and viewed with a PDF viewer,
>   the active link area will be misplaced.